# IF Statement Error when using mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I have been declared `IF` statement using mariadb like below.

```
set @number_of_technicians = (select COUNT(*) from additional_participants where username = 'JK1001');

IF @number_of_technicians > 0 THEN
        select @number_of_technicians as amount;
END IF
```

When i execute the code it throw some errors like below.

```
[SQL] 
set @number_of_technicians = (select COUNT(*) from additional_participants where username = 'JK1001');
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.001ms

[SQL] 

IF @number_of_technicians > 0 THEN
        select @number_of_technicians as amount;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

Is there something wrong with my code..?

I execute the code using `Navicat Premium`

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = 0, NULL, COUNT(*))
    from additional_participants
    where username = 'JK1001';
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.

According to mariadb official website `https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/if-function/` here is the correct `IF` statement declaration.

```
set @number_of_technicians = (select COUNT(*) from additional_participants where username = 'JK1001');

SELECT IF (@number_of_technicians > 0, (select @number_of_technicians as amount), (select 'null' as result) ) as result
```

Statement above will give result like below.

```
+-------+
|result |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
```